# Some Sandwich properties for complete Riemannian metrics

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I search for  some  properties  $P$  for  complete  Riemannian manifolds which  satisfy  a  kind of    Sandwich property.

More  precisely I  search  for  those  properties $P$ for  complete Riemannian manifolds which  satisfy the following:

For  every  manifold  $M$  with $3$  complete Riemannian metrics $g_1\leq h \leq g_2$, if  $(M,g_1)$ and $(M,g_2)$ satisfy $P$ then $(M,h)$ satisfies  $P$, too.

What  properties $P$ are some examples  of this  situation?

In particular, is  "Flatness"  an example of such squeeze property?

Comment: Flatness certainly isn't; consider a conformally euclidian metric $h:=e^f g_{\rm eucl}$ for some bounded function $f$ on $\mathbb R^n$, then $h$ isn't flat if $f$ is general.

Comment: On type of property one can thing of though is being of prescribed (e.g. linear, quadratic, maximal) volume growth.

Comment: @Henri  Is  completeness  a  consequence of  bounded ness of  $e^f$?

Comment: Yes, two metrics that are quasi-isometric are either both complete or both incomplete

Comment: (boundedness of $f$ is the key, not the boundedness of $e^f$. You need that $e^f$ is uniformly bounded away from zero also)

Comment: The intuitive idea should be that curvature is a quantity at the level of two derivatives of the metric, and we know that if three functions $f_1 \leq h \leq f_2$, there are no guarantee that $|\nabla f_1| \leq |\nabla h| \leq  |\nabla f_2|$. ($h$ can be much more oscillatory than either $f_1$ and $f_2$). So realistically you only really expect to control things of regularity level at the level of the metric or its integrals. Volume being certainly one of them as Henri said.